# Trouble following Birrel and Davies in acomputing Bogoliuov coefficients

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, coordinate-systems, hawking-radiation

I'm having trouble following a computation from the book "quantum fields in curved spacetime" by Birrel and Davies.
In the chapter Where the authors describe particle creation by a collapsing spherical body they use two different coordinate systems to describe the outside region : $$ds^2= C(r) du dv$$ with $$u = t-r^*-R_{0}^*\\ v= t + r^*-R_{0}^*$$ and  $$r*=\int{C(r)^{-1}}dr$$ For the inside region They use $$ds^2= A(U,V) dU dV$$
with $$U=\tau -r+R_{0}\\V=\tau +r-R_{0}$$
and the relation between $R_{0}$ (which is the starting position of the surface of the collapsing body) and $R_0^*$ is the sae as the one between $r$ and $r^*$

They proceed to define $$U=\alpha(u)\\v=\beta(V)$$ and then to compute $$\alpha'(u)=dU/du=(1-\dot{R})C\{[AC(1-\dot{R}^2)+\dot{R}^2]^{1/2}-\dot{R}\}^{-1}\\ \beta '(V) = dv/dV= C^{-1}(1+\dot{R})^{-1}\{[AC(1-\dot{R}^2)+\dot{R}^2]^{1/2}+\dot{R}\}$$ by matching the two coordinate systems at $r=R(\tau)$ wich is the collapsing surface. This last step is giving me headaches because I can't seem to find a good way to tackle it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Looks like other people also had trouble deriving it. Birrel is very bad with not skipping important steps. If you still need help on this, let me know. I will be making a video soon showing the steps on YouTube.